# "no jpl in java.library.path" Error when running my chatbot application (SWI-Prolog and Java)

Tags: macos, java, prolog

I have been experiencing this problem for days now. I am trying to run my projects on my new Mac device (M1 MBA Ventura 13.3.1). I'm new to macOS so I went and resorted to a few youtube videos on installing what I need for my projects at university (IDEs, packages, etc.). I mainly installed what I need through either homebrew or macports.

I can compile and run simple .java programs, but when it comes to my bigger and more complex programs, this issue always pops up. I cannot even run .jar files my friends send me.

To be specific, I am currently developing this simple chatbot where I used PROLOG to develop my knowledge base and Java for the user interface.

This is what the error looks like:

[image: error]

I tried researching the problem and there were people who experienced the same thing. However, since I'm new to macOS, some of the responses didn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please don't post textual messages as images. They can be difficult to see on a smaller screen, can't be interpreted by text-to-speech, search terms can't be copy-pasted... this applies to most SE sites. Instead copy-paste messages / commands / configs to question and use the code brackets on the toolbar `{ }` to keep the formatting.

Comment: I see no question.